# how to give mysql database table reference in external javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am writing the below line in my external **.js** file....

```
var myid=project_subtaskInstanceList[0].progress
```

My **project_subtask controller** is like this

```
def show(Project_subtask project_subtaskInstance) {
        respond project_subtaskInstance
    }
```

The javascript is giving an error

```
ReferenceError: project_subtaskInstanceList is not defined
```

Comment: You can't pass references to server-side objects to the browser. JS only has access to the stuff in the page your server generated, it doesn't have direct access to anything on the server. It would be best to create some sort of server-side interface that serves the results you want to get in a format that JS can digest. You could then request them via XHR. You could also generate the results when creating the page and embed them in the page so JS can access them. Either way, JSON would likely be the best data exchange format since it is easily parsable in the browser via `JSON.parse`.

Comment: can u please give some example, i am new to this

Comment: I suspect an example wouldn't fit on the answer form SO provides. I would suggest having a look online for some tutorials.